# I'm trying to add elements into my list using the range function but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, arrays, list, range, index-error

```
numberinput = []
for x in range(1, 11):
  arrayinput = input("Type the number you want to add to the array")
  numberinput[x] = arrayinput
print(numberinput)
```

I've created an empty list and what im trying to is, im trying to increment x to add 10 numbers into the list but it just displays

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python lists, you can only refer to elements that exist.  Do it like this:

```
numberinput = []
for x in range(10):
  arrayinput = input("Type the number you want to add to the array")
  numberinput.append( arrayinput )
print(numberinput)
```

Note that numbering starts at 0, so this will ask for 10 numbers.  Also note they will be stored as strings.